# Update read-only field ("completed") in listitem programmatically

Tags: list, column

I want programmatically update (change) a read-only field (the "Completed" column) of a listitem in a survey, but on everthing I do, I get the message that it's not possible to update a ready only field.

This is my code on the moment:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
  using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID))
  {
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
      site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
      web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
      SPList list = web.Lists[listTitle];
      SPListItem item = list.Items[itemID];

      item["Completed"] = "Yes";
      item.Update();
      web.Update();
      site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
      web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Just wondering... are you trying to programmatically complete a task item (with some workflow attached)? If that's the case, I fear that the above method won't work. Leave a comment if you need some further reference.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you turn off ReadOnly while you're updating the field, and then set it back? Something along the lines of this (haven't tested it).

```
SPList list = web.Lists[listTitle];
var completedField = list.Fields["Completed"];
completedField.ReadOnlyField = false;
completedField.Update();

SPListItem item = list.Items[itemID];

item["Completed"] = "Yes";
item.Update();

completedField.ReadOnlyField = true;
completedField.Update();

web.Update();
```

PS: If the field has been added to the content type, you might have to update the content type as well. [Reference](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/sharepointdevelopment/thread/70d2398a-0451-4ea2-b0a6-1c1caa45044c)

Comment: Like omlin says: "the time while the field stays in non-ReadOnly mode is so little (actually, it'll be just a few milliseconds) that probability of such concurrent access is dead small."

Comment: @tarjeieo yep, and even if this happens, user will just get this field in the edit form. And right after this the field will be switched back into ReadOnly mode. Hence, user will not be able to save its value anyway (ok, unless another ReadOnly flag switch will happen exactly when the user presses `Save`). So ridiculous, really :(

Comment: amagonna vote you up again ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should leverage [SPField.ReadOnlyField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.readonlyfield.aspx) property to achieve the desired behavior.

Before updating item, set ReadOnlyField for the "Completed" field to false and update the field ([SPField.Update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms416125.aspx)). Then, you will be able to update item. Finally, change ReadOnlyField back to false and update the field again.

Comment: I reckon the time while the field stays in non-ReadOnly mode is so little (actually, it'll be just a few milliseconds) that probability of such concurrent access is dead small.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you can run as administrator and update any list item field. But you should ask the business question what reason do you have to update this field? And is there another proper way to do it, like through a workflow. This field is used for workflow task tracking.

Answer (score 0):

The field you are trying to change is a **computed** one. You can't change its value, no matter what the settings for the field are. You'll have to reverse engineer it in order to find out how it computes its values, then change the fields it is using in its formula.

By the way, the raw values in the *"Completed"* field of a survey are 0 for not completed and 1 for completed.

So I've spent a few hours trying to come up with a way to set a survey completion status programmatically. All the *Completed* field does is reading the value from the *"Level"* field, and change it from a number to a string. However, there is no way to change the value of *"Level"* without delving into SQL. Try changing it via the object model and you get an error without any meaningful message. Check the correlating ID in the logs and it says you've got invalid SQL. Wow.

Answer (score 0):

May be this is due to incompatibility of provided property.
It is a check box type property and the assigned value is a string. If you could try to assign a bool value to this "Completed" field instead of a string value it might get work.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a few hours in reflector too and I found that you can call Checkout() method by reflection on your newly added SPListItem without calling Update() method.

The result is that your item is saved but not completed.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a custom column "IsComplete" that is not read-only.